# Use props from slot as local component data vue

Tags: vue.js

Hello im using a layout with a slot without wherein i render my pages. now when layout is rendered it fetches some data and pass it in the slot as props. I can easily access the props within the template however i cannot use it as a local data. i was planning to use that data as a filter when fetching data

```
<template lang="">
    <Layout v-slot:default="{ apptAccess }">
        <h1>{{ apptAccess.ticketStatus }}</h1>

        <h1>Mentors</h1>
        <div class="grid grid-cols-4 gap-5 mx-auto my-10">
            <div class="mx-auto" v-for="Person in persons">
                <PersonCard :PersonDetails="person" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </Layout>
</template>
<script>

data() {
        return {
            mentors: [],
            apptAccess: null,
        };
    },
```

I'm stuck with this problem as i cant even access the slots. any help is greatly appreciated thanks so much

Comment: You can't define a slot prop as part of the parent component's state.  It goes against component encapsulation. You _can_ pass the slot prop as a parameter to a method belonging to the parent, otherwise use normal component props/emit logic between parent and child, which can be utilized to affect the value of a slot prop in such a way that it doesn't need to be referenced or modified by the parent's script code.

Answer (score 0):

[Vue SFC Playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

Use `defineExpose()` to expose your data to the parent component and access it through a template ref:

Layout.vue

```
<script setup>
import {reactive} from 'vue';
const apptAccess = reactive({});
defineExpose({apptAccess});
setTimeout(()=>Object.assign(apptAccess, {ticketStatus:'Ticket status: ok'}), 1000);
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <slot v-bind="{apptAccess}"/>
  </div>
</template>
```

App.vue

```
<script setup>
import Layout from './Layout.vue';
import {ref} from 'vue';
const $layout = ref();
setTimeout(() => alert($layout.value.apptAccess.ticketStatus), 2000);
</script>

<template lang="">
    <Layout ref="$layout" #="{apptAccess}">
        <h1>{{ apptAccess.ticketStatus }}</h1>
    </Layout>
</template>
```

But a better way could be lifting the state to the parent component and access it in the child either through `provide/inject` or `v-model`. But in that case I would fetch the data in the parent component. It's not good when a state is mutated outside its component.

[Vue SFC Playground: provide/inject example](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)